# RequireJS - Exporting a Set of Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, dependency-injection, requirejs, dependencies

I'm experiencing an issue with **RequireJS** where I'm not able to *export* a set of functions when I have a **require** statement.

Let's assume I have a file called **mySubFile.js**, where, first I need to inject **jQuery** and then another dependency. Now, Let's suppose I have **myFunction** and I want to export it in order to get called from another file.

```
define('mySubFile', ['jquery'], function ($) {
    require(['dependency1'], function (dependency1) {

       let myFunction = function(){ return "Hey There"; }

       return : {
                    myFunction : myFunction
       }

    });
});
```

Now let's assume that I want to call that function from **myFile.js**:

```
define('myFile', ['jquery'], function ($) {
    require(['mySubFile'], function (mySubFile) {

       console.log(mySubFile.myFunction());

    });
});
```

This does not work. I get:

> Cannot read property 'myFunction' of undefined.

On the other side, If I define **mySubFile.js** as follows:

```
define('mySubFile', ['jquery', 'dependency1'], function ($, dependency1) {

   let myFunction = function(){ return "Hey There"; }

   return : {
               myFunction : myFunction
   }

});
```

I can access **myFunction** but I NEED to first resolve **jQuery**.

I'm struggling trying to find a solution to this but still haven't found anything.

**How Can I Solve this?**

Comment: You mean you need jquery before mySubFile module?

Comment: @NiteshI need to inject jQuery before anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the code you show in your question, this is really the way to go:

```
define('mySubFile', ['jquery', 'dependency1'], function ($, dependency1) {
```

But you don't want to use it because:

> can access **myFunction** but I NEED to first resolve **jQuery**.

Well, sure `jquery` will have to be resolved before you can return a value, but let's assume for a second that there's some magic that would allow your other attempt to return the value you want and let's just look at it from the perspective of what gets resolved when. This is what you have:

```
define('mySubFile', ['jquery'], function ($) {
    require(['dependency1'], function (dependency1) {
```

Here's what happens:

1. The `define` call is executed. RequireJS sees a module name (`mySubFile`), a dependency list `['jquery']` and a callback.
2. RequireJS resolves `jquery` and calls the callback with it.
3. The `require` call is executed. RequireJS sees a dependency list and a callback.
4. RequireJS resolves `dependency1` and calls the callback.

Here too, `jquery` has to be resolved before you could return anything. Having a `require` inside the `define` callback does not change anything to this.

Getting the `require` call inside the `define` to work the way you want would need significant rewriting. The problem you're hitting on there, by the way, is not specific to RequireJS but a problem common to all asynchronous code. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for the general problem and approaches to it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm aware of the asynchronous nature of the problem. If I do like you said at the beginning I haven't any *undefined* issues but my application just breaks up somehow since I'm not resolving jquery first. I'm taking a look at that question you've linked but can't find a way to resolve jquery first. Maybe using **$document(ready)**?

Comment: It's not clear to me why you're running into a problem. `jquery` is resolved before the callback to `define` is called. If `dependency1` *also* depends on `jquery` then you need to put `jquery` in its list of dependencies: either in its `define` call, or if it is a third-party non-AMD piece of code, you need to set a `shim` in RequireJS' configuration that lists `jquery` as a dependency.

Comment: For instance, right now I've a problem where I have to trigger a given function which is located into another js file after **$(document).ready** but somehow I get **externalFile.thatFunction()** undefined since externalFile seems to get resolved at the same time as jQuery does.

Answer (score 1):

If you always need jQuery to be available before your module, you can do it like this:

```
define("mySubFile", function(require, exports, module){ 
    var a = require("jQuery"), // dependency
        b = require("knockout"); // dependency
    /* rest of the code for this module */ 

    let myFunction = function(){ return "Hey There"; }

   return : {
            myFunction : myFunction
         }
});
```

Comment: The problem is not caused by jQuery and I'm already able to get it available before anything else. I'm having an issue on accessing an external function from another file when that subfile has a require statement.